# What values should I choose for P and Q?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to forecast energy data generated by [LoadProfileGenerater](http://www.loadprofilegenerator.de/). This data is generated every half hour for 2 years. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/).

[image]

I have checked it for stationarity using Dickey Fuller Test

```
Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:
Test Statistic                -1.684705e+01
p-value                        1.126331e-29
#Lags Used                     5.200000e+01
Number of Observations Used    3.503500e+04
Critical Value (5%)           -2.861623e+00
Critical Value (1%)           -3.430537e+00
Critical Value (10%)          -2.566814e+00
```

Results indicate that the time series is very close to stationarity (**Test Statistic < Critical Value (1%)**).

I have therefore used `ARMA` for forecasting.

[image]

However I am not being able to determine the values of `p` and `q`. Both, PACF and ACF charts indicate intersection with the upper confidence line at **0.01**.

[image]

What values for **p** and **q** should I use?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried differencing as suggested in the comments. Rolling mean has dropped to nearly 0 but rolling std has increased to 0.75. ACF and PACF have generated similar charts as without differencing.

Source used for Differencing:

```
# Differencing
ts_log = np.log(ts)
ts_log_diff = ts_log - ts_log.shift()
ts_log_diff.dropna(inplace=True)
stationarity.test_stationarity(ts_log_diff)
```

[image: After Differencing]

```
Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:
Test Statistic                   -64.965417
p-value                            0.000000
#Lags Used                        50.000000
Number of Observations Used    35036.000000
Critical Value (5%)               -2.861622
Critical Value (1%)               -3.430537
Critical Value (10%)              -2.566814
```

Comment: Good question. I see that Dickey Fuller Test shows your series is almost stationary, but I have experienced that the test is not that accurate. For example I can see that Rolling Mean/Std are not zero ( ~ 0.5 out of your original series ranging between 1.5-2.0 for majority of peaks) as they should be. I would try "Differencing" to zero your rolling mean/std as much as you can and then try to find the p and q.

Comment: @MajidMortazavi I have added the differencing results. But now I will have to use ARIMA instead of ARMA right?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think the simple answer is yes as parameter D also shows up besides P and Q! Check here: http://www.statsref.com/HTML/index.html?arima.html
Also as you said your rolling std isn't good yet!! Maybe take a few sequential differencing until because become nearly zero! There are many techniques, Differencing was one of them maybe you should try others! Honestly I do not like this ARIMA, ARMA models, very old and so empirical in nature!! Maybe there is better way! How you tried Facebook Prophet?